# Wrong computation of assortativity in igraph

Tags: r, networking, graph, igraph

I am trying to compute the assortativity of my network for different vertex attributes. However everytime I want to compute the **assortativity_nominal()**, a fatal error appears and R terminates. What's funny, though, is that I also have the same variable which is represented as numerical and executing the method **assortativity()** gives me an output. I just want to know if both method return the same coefficient. In general my network is characterized that there are some missing values in some features, but I replaced these values by a fixed value.

```
V(myGraph)$class[is.nan(V(myGraph)$class)] <- 99
V(myGraph)$argmax_column[is.na(V(myGraph)$argmax_column)] <- "p99"
V(myGraph)$argmax_column[V(myGraph)$argmax_column == ""] <- "p99"


unique(V(myGraph)$class)
[1]  2  1  0 99

unique(V(myGraph)$argmax_column)
[1] "p1"    "p2"    "p3"    "p99"
```

Another problem is that I have to convert the **V(myGraph)$argmax_column** to a factor, otherwise R will be terminate.

```
> assortativity(myGraph, V(myGraph)$class, directed=T)
[1] 0.01432427
> assortativity_nominal(myGraph, V(myGraph)$argmax_column, directed=T)
[1] FATAL ERROR - R TERMINATES
```

I also converted the variable as a factor, but then the order is different / unequal to the numerical feature and will return other results for the same data.

```
> assortativity_nominal(myGraph, as.factor(V(myGraph)$argmax_column), directed=T)
[1] 0.0371235
```

I mean the computation for the assortativity coefficient should be the same even for nominal or numerical values, because both features are equal in their meaning (same values, just other datatypes).

Comment: As per documentation, `types` argument values are as assumed to be integer numbers, starting with one in `assortativity_nominal`, seems does not hold in your case. In the end case, are the numeric value of the factor levels same as expected?

Comment: Yes you are right! Well if I convert the nominal values into factors like "p1", it will be transform into number 2 as an example, which is unequal to the class. Therefore the results are quite different. So I am not sure why assortativity_nominal is even implemented if the results are different